# Theoretical vs Practical knowledge

Tags: skills

I'm a freshman in a Computer Science academy. Every semester there are a lot of different classes like **Discrete Math**, **Linear Algebra**, **Algorithms** etc most of which I find very interesting. Unfortunatly each day has only 24 hours and I find myself unable to get a more indepth knowledge of each of those classes, beyond the basic level required to pass my exams with a good grade. Meanwhile I understand that I also need to have some concrete practial experience in a computer language or two and be able to demonstrate that I am proficient in it.

Thus I am torn between studying more theoretical concepts like **Math**, **Data Structures**, **Algorithms** etc and creating personal projects like android applications, games etc in order to have a strong portfolio that I can later present to a possible employer.

My question is: **What should I prioritize, aquiring theoretical knowledge around computer science, or getting practical knowledge around a specific programming language?**

Comment: If I were you I would go for the theoretical knowledge now, since after school you will have very little chances to learn more about theory, and lots of opportunities to acquire practical knowledge. This is unfortunate, because a sound theoretical knowledge can often save a lot of work and many headaches.

Comment: To add to Giorgio, do not completely skip on the practical part either. Many times graduates come from a college knowing the difference between radix and insertion sorts and how to implement and know when to use a b-tree over an array, but have very little coding practice and their code is pretty much worthless, so it takes the company around 3-6 (depends on the candidate) months to teach them how to code.

Comment: And this is why career/education questions are offtopic.  The answer is always a form of "Do A, but don't not do B either.  Well, it depends, sometimes do A, sometimes do B.  Good luck."

Comment: (1) do one semester practical stuff (2) do one semester theory (3) GOTO (1)   (and beforehand, throw a coin if you want to start with 1 or 2 first).

Comment: Programming languages and frameworks are ephemeral (except for C and Javascript, which will live forever).  You'll be learning new ones the rest of your life.  Fundamentals are eternal.

Comment: This depends almost entirely on the particular jobs and employers you'll be interviewing for. To hyperbolize the point, if you want to flip burgers for a living, you can skip *both* the practical *and* the theoretical! That said, there's great value *for you* in having practical experience *founded* on theoretical knowledge. (Even if you want to flip burgers professionally, I'd argue.)

Answer (score 1):

> What should I prioritize, aquiring theoretical knowledge around
>   computer science, or getting practical knowledge around a specific
>   programming language?

Why not apply concepts of computer science, maths, and algorithms with a specific language?

I don't think that what you do outside of coursework has to be dedicated to one or the other.  I would focus on what is most interesting to you; the fact that you're coding for the purpose of learning and enjoy it already sets you apart from those who code only as required by class work.